# Thread safety when using XML API in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a question about thread safety using XML in VB.NET.

I have an application that manages an `XmlDocument` object as the user creates new items/makes changes to existing items. I already know that I need to synchronize calls to `XmlDocument.CreateElement(...)`. My question is, can I then proceed to build the returned element without synchronization, then just synchronize again when appending that element into the `XmlDocument`?

This is what I think I can do, I just need to make sure it is thread-safe like I think it is:

```
' "doc" object already exists as an XmlDocument
SyncLock doc
  Dim newsub As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("submission")
End SyncLock

' use "newsub" here without synchronization

SyncLock doc
  doc.Item("submissions").AppendChild(newsub)
End SyncLock
```

When adding the children of "newsub" then I would also synchronize only when creating each element.

As a followup to this question, would I be better off just synchronizing the entire building of the "newsub" object? The reason I think doing it like above is better is for performance, but I am not by any means an expert in whether I am actually making a meaningful impact on performance, or just complicating things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, when using any class derived from [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx), you will need synchronization, as it's documentation explicitly states:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This means you'll need synchronization when appending children, as you've shown.

> As a followup to this question, would I be better off just synchronizing the entire building of the "newsub" object? The reason I think doing it like above is better is for performance, but I am not by any means an expert in whether I am actually making a meaningful impact on performance, or just complicating things.

It depends - if you're going to be doing anything that may cause it to be usable from multiple threads, then you may need to synchronize it.

In your above code, it should be safe to work with `newsub` outside of the synchronization, since it's not part of the actual document tree until you append it as a child.  This will reduce the amount of time where `doc` is locked, which *could* reduce contention if `doc` is being used from multiple threads.